# Moving of rows in using pandas (Total Beginner)

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and pandas library. I have 12000 rows and 3 columns for instance:

```
A           B          C
Husband     Test1      $1200
Kids        Test1      $1288
Wife        Test1      $1232
Cousin      Test1      $3265
```

Expected Result:

```
A           B          C
Husband     Test1      $1200
Wife        Test1      $1232 
Kids        Test1      $1288
Cousin      Test1      $3265
```

---

```
A           B          C
Husband     Test2      $1200
Kids        Test2      $1288
Cousin      Test2      $3265
Wife        Test2      $1232
```

Expected Result:

```
A           B          C
Husband     Test2      $1200
Wife        Test2      $1232 
Kids        Test2      $1288
Cousin      Test2      $3265
```

So Where ever I see the word "Wife", I want the entire row to be moved below Husband. I have used 2 examples above. This is what I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")

df1=pd.DataFrame()

df1 = df.append(df[df["Relationship"] == "Husband"])

df1 = df.append(df[df["Relationship"] == "Wife"])

df1 = df.append(df[df["Relationship"] == "Kids"])

df1 = df.append(df[df["Relationship"] == "Cousin"])

print(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ordered categoricals for specified custom order of column `A`, so [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) get specified order:

```
 df = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")

df['A'] = pd.Categorical(df.A, ordered=True, categories=['Husband','Wife','Kids','Cousin'])

df = df.sort_values(['B','A'], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
         A      B      C
0  Husband  Test1  $1200
1     Wife  Test1  $1232
2     Kids  Test1  $1288
3   Cousin  Test1  $3265
```